# M1 Mac Torch configuration

Tags: python-3.x, torch

I installed torch via https://developer.apple.com/metal/pytorch/

```
% pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
```

I added it to my command path

```
% echo $path # removed other paths for brevity
/Users/pav/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/torch/bin
```

this is how i am adding it in my .zshrc file

```
#TORCH
export PATH=/Users/pav/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/torch/bin:$PATH
```

yet if try to import torch in a python file i get a Import could not be resolved

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

am I missing something?

Comment: The PATH only is ability to run executables; that's distinct from `PYTHONPATH` or (in the Python interpreter) `sys.path`, which are what you need for `import` to work.

Comment: I'd suggest, in your Python interpreter, printing `sys.path`. Where is it looking for `site-packages`? If it's not looking in `/Users/pav/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages`, where _is_ it looking? You don't want to force a library with C dependencies compiled for Python 3.9 into, say, a Python 3.8 or 3.10's path, so don't just add it blindly -- figure out what's going wrong first.

Comment: Better to use the three-space backtick code formatting when you have content in different languages; when you use four-space indents you can't (as conveniently) indicate what kind of syntax highlighting is appropriate for each individual section.

Comment: Anyhow -- _personally_, I install pytorch as well as Python itself on MacOS using [Nix](https://www.nixos.org/); that way you get a completely self-contained dependency chain that built together.

Comment: import sys
print(sys.path)

results in 

/usr/local/bin/python /Volumes/dev/python/tourchTest.py
pav@mrhyde python % /usr/local/bin/python /Volumes/dev/python/tourchTest.py
['/Volumes/dev/python', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1
/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages']

Comment: [Edit] that into the question rather than adding it as a comment, but that's exactly the problem: You used a Python 3.9 pip3, but you're using a Python 3.11 Python interpreter. Your pip needs to be working on the same interpreter you want to actually use.

Comment: Consider using `python -m venv` to create a virtualenv with the same `python` that's first in the PATH, and installing pytorch into _that_ virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks man, I will look into it some more later tonight, thank you for your feedback. I'm super noob at python and macOS to be honest, but I'll look into this nix thing.

Comment: (For an example of using Nix to install the Python environment for a fairly complex software project that uses pytorch -- with a README describing the whys and wherefores -- see https://github.com/eth-sri/lmql/pull/139/files; mind, that tool's dependencies isn't _just_ Python; we're also using Nix to install node.js and a bunch of javascript dependencies for the web-ui build, f/e).